# I need the latest entry from 2 tables using SQL in Excel 2016 VBA that connects to a PG SQL db. The search data is exactly the same

Tags: sql, excel, vba

I'm connecting to a PostGresSQl running SQL query in Excel VBA

Here is my query that works fine accessing 1 table:

```
Const sqlconnection = "Provider=visoledb;"
Dim conn As New Connection
conn.ConnectionString = sqlconnection

conn.Open
Dim rs As Recordset

Worksheets.Add(After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)).Name = "FINDDATA"
    Sheets("FINDDATA").Select
    ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Select
        
        v = "SELECT DISTINCT latest.id, " _
            & "SUBSTRING(latestRECORD,1,10)date, " _
            & "SUBSTRING(latestRECORD,12,7)code, " _
            & "SUBSTRING(latestRECORD,20,80)term " _
            & "FROM ( SELECT id, MAX(CAST(date AS VARCHAR(10)) + '|' + RIGHT(code,7) + '|' + RIGHT(term,80)) as latestRECORD " _
                        & "FROM table1 WHERE id IN (2,3,6,7,14,22,29,54) AND code LIKE '22K' " _
                & "GROUP BY id ) AS latest " _
            & "ORDER BY id "
    Set rs = conn.Execute(v)
    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:=rs, Destination:=Range("A1"))
        .Refresh
    End With
    conn.Close
```

However I need to search another "table2" which has exactly the same column names and uses exactly the same WHERE details.
I tried using UNION  ALL, but can't get it to work.

I have to use SUBSTRINGs to join the data as I'm limited as to what I can use i.e. I can't use LIMIT

Could someone tell me how I should join the other table to the above query?
Thank you

Comment: Can't use PowerQuery?

Comment: To echo Skin statement with a little of my experience... being skilled with VBA can be a curse as you lose track of how technology advances because you and almost do anything with VBA (though requiring effort).  IN my experience, his left me blind to several key technologies (power query being one). Such tools are simpler a.  Also, you should clarify if you want to join or append. Good luck either way.

Comment: With regards to Join or Append. It's the latest record from either table I need to see the data from. I will take a look at PowerQuery to see if it is something I can use with Excel.